# is it possible to add one Firebase URL in my two application.?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i'm beginner for android studio and Firebase,I have done one small Firebase project. In this project i get Url from firebase console site when i add my project package name. My question is it possible to use one firebase project url to another (different package name )new project. If possible means pleas guide me..

Answer (score 0):

Add two Android apps to your Firebase project, download the google-services.json and add it to both Android Studio project. I do this all the time and it works without problems for me.

If you are having problems, describe what you've tried and where it fails.